# Flask path to css

Tags: python, html, css, flask, frameworks

How can i repair errors with my path? I would like my html in a flask to load my stylesheet into the project, but it throws a lot of jinja2 errors. I'm starting with flask framework.

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template
import os.path

TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.abspath('PROJECTS DEV\Extractor_APP\templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.abspath('PROJECTS DEV\Extractor_APP\static\styles')

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=TEMPLATE_DIR, static_folder=STATIC_DIR)


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("homepage.html")

@app.route("/<name>")
def name(name):
    return render_template("namepage.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

````
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flask learning</title>
        <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/homepage.css') }}">
        <title>Home page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Home page!</h1>
        {% for text in content%}
        <p>{{text}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

In the root folder of your project, create a `static` folder for static files like css and js files. See example below:

> To generate URLs for static files, use the special 'static' endpoint
> name:
>
> `url_for('static', filename='style.css')`
>
> The file has to be stored on the filesystem as static/style.css.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/quickstart/#static-files

There is also no need to specify static and template folders. Just use: `app = Flask(__name__)`

Comment: I actually has 2 folders, 1 for html its templates and 1 for js/css etc. static im my project folder, but its doesnt work

Comment: You can  try to initialize Flask with __name__ alone.